# Sessions not work after adding Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, header

I use ajax to send/receive some data with jQuery,
In chrome I will get some errors when I use Ajax and I searched in StackOverflow and I found I should add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` and because I have a custom header in my jQuery code, I added `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-TokenCode');` to my php code.

but after adding this `headers` my sessions not work!

what should I do ?

**UPDATE:**

Domain name is the same

Comment: Is the site you are using to get data from with AJAX from a different domain?  We need a little more information in order to help.

Comment: domain name is the same

Comment: If the domain is the same, the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` shouldn't be needed at all.  How about taking it back to the original problem - the errors you got when using AJAX.  Were the errors just in chrome?  Did they also happen in firefox? (Internet Explorer, if you want to support it)  What was the error you got?  Take the question back to your original problem rather than what was introduced when adding unneeded headers, and you'll likely find a solution quicker.